# Настройка autoWidth в owl carousel 2 не отрабатывает на iphone - как исправить?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, owl-carousel

Есть [owl carousel 2](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/autowidth.html) c такими настройками

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(".marathon").owlCarousel({
    margin:15,
    //autoWidth: true,
    lazyLoad:true,
    pagination: false,
    responsiveRefreshRate: 200,
    animateOut: "fadeOut",
    responsive:{
       0:{
           items:2,
           nav:false
         },
       541:{
           items:3,
           nav:true,
           autoWidth: true  
         }
    }
   });
});
```

На всех устройствах с `autoWidth: true` отрабатывает хорошо за исключением `iphone`, где не успевают подгрузиться картинки, чтобы верно отработала ширина и по итогу хоть карусель и работает, но шрифты огромные. Поэтому, оставил `autoWidth` пока только для десктопа.

Как это можно исправить, чтобы везде отработало?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В моем случае сработало задание стилей

```
.owl-stage {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-box;
    display: box;
}
```

Comment: `display: box;` - это что-то новенькое или всё-таки значение `flex`?

Comment: @Deonis https://caniuse.com/#search=display%20box
поддержка подходящая в отличие от `flex`

Comment: это называется, `привет из прошлого` ---  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16280040/css3-flexbox-display-box-vs-flexbox-vs-flex

Comment: @Air, не то слово... 2009 год ))

Comment: И за что минус? за то, что поделился с сообществом решением, которое может помочь тем, кто столкнется с аналогичной проблемой?

Comment: Это минус от меня....